# numerical analysis finding $f(x) $of iteration formula using secant method

Tags: numerical-methods

The iteration formula given below was obtained by applying secant method to some function $f(x)$. What was $f(x)$? What can this formula be used for?

$$
x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{(3-10^{x_n})(x_n - x_{n-1})}{10^{x_n}- 10^{x_{n-1}}}
$$

Comment: How do we compute f(x) when xn is raised as a power?

Comment: @MJD.Thanks for editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for the secant iteration is:
$$
x_{n + 1} = x_n - f(x_n) \frac{x_n - x_{n - 1}}{f(x_n) - f(x_{n - 1})}
$$
So you must identify the second term with your second term:
$$
f(x_n) \frac{x_n - x_{n -1}}{f(x_n) - f(x_{n - 1})}
  = - \frac{(3 - 10^{x_n})(x_n - x_{n - 1})}{10^{x_n} - 10^{x_{n - 1}}}
$$
Thus the function must be such that $f(x_n) - f(x_{n - 1}) = \alpha(10^{x_n} - 10^{x_{n - 1}})$, so $f(x) = \alpha (c - 10^x)$ for constants $\alpha$ and $c$; and the factor $3 - 10^{x_n}$ gives away that $c = 3$, so $f(x) = \alpha (3 - 10^x)$. As long as $\alpha \ne 0$ it is arbitrary. (Yes, part of this is really unnecessary; but is serves to make sure we aren't being given a fake.)

Somebody is looking for $\log 3$...

Comment: @ vonbrand. Thanks for a quick response. I think that the f(xn) in numerator should have a exact matching for f(xn) in denominator. Please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Avinesh, what is $f(x_n) - f(x_{n - 1})$ for the $f$ I give?

Comment: @ vonbrand. f (xn) is equal to α(10xn). when matched directly.

Comment: @ vonbrand. The f(xn) at numerator may not be necessarily be same as the one on denominator?

Comment: @Avinesh, yes, and I'm checking it is so. But the denominator is $f(x_n) - f(x_{n - 1})$, not just one $f(x_n)$.

Comment: @ vonbrand. Thanks for the clarification